# including *.so lib in android app using Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, android-native-library

I want to use *.so file in my android app so I copied file to "libs\armeabi\libctrl_gpio.so" as suggested at some websites. When I run and create apk file, Eclipse creates this folder(inside apk)!

```
"lib\armeabi\libctrl_gpio.so"
```

It changes "libs" to "lib"
and at runtime when app wants to load library using this code :

```
System.loadLibrary("ctrl_gpio");
```

I got error :

```
Trying to load lib /data/data/shopping.shop/lib/libctrl_gpio.so
Added shared lib /data/data/shopping.shop/lib/libctrl_gpio.so
JNI_OnLoad
failed to open /dev/ctrl_gpio -- No such file or directory.
JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1) in /data/data/shopping.shop/lib/libctrl_gpio.so
WARNING: Could not load library!
```

You see at line one that the path is "lib/libctrl_gpio.so" not "lib\armeabi\libctrl_gpio.so" as inside the apk file!

Also at line 4 the path is "/dev/ctrl_gpio" !!!!!!!!!!

I don't understand why it happens and is this my problem that prevents loading of library?
I searched and saw lots of websites and questions but none of them solved my problem. Any help will highly appreciated. I'm newbie to android so provide me with details. thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the .so from?

Comment: the library has been compiled for another arch probably

Comment: From another android app source ( the company gave it to me to develop another pp). What now? What can I do?

Comment: _"Also at line 4 the path is "/dev/ctrl_gpio""_ Well, maybe libctrl_gpio is trying to access the **device** /dev/ctrl_gpio. Whether apps are allowed to do that, I have no idea.